# Tails Encrypted Persistent Storage access time

Tags: tails, encryption

How do I find the last time a Tails Encrypted Persistent Storage was accessed? Also is it possible to find the last time Tails was started?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I find the last time a Tails Encrypted Persistent Storage was accessed?

Here is a way to show the last 10 modified files in your Persistent folder:

```
find . -type f -printf '%TF %TT %p\n' | sort | tail -10
```

(navigate to this folder first, of course)

Please note that this command only shows last *modifications* (and does not take into account if your file is just read). I hope it will suit your usecase

Comment: If the Tails encrypted storage partition has not been unlocked is there any way to see the last time it was accessed?